# iterm2を開いた時に上記のようにsyntax errorが表示されます。

Tags: bash

```
1.bash
Last login: Sat Nov 25 22:23:12 on ttys001
-bash: eval: line 43: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

iterm2を開いた時に上記のようにsyntax errorが表示されます。
対処方法を教えて下さい、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~/.bashrc` や `~/.profile` など、bash が立ち上がる際に読み込まれるファイルの中身をよく読んでください。エラーメッセージにあるように、43行目が怪しいです。`unexpected end of file` とエラーが出ているので、閉じカッコが不足していたり、`if` に対応する `fi` が無かったりなどしていないか確認してください。

iTerm2 ということは macOS だと思いますが、その場合、見た目で良いように見えても、ダブルクォーテーションが `"` ではなく `“` や `”` になっていることがあるので、その点にもお気をつけください。

Comment: .bash_profileのなかに
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
が3行連続で記述していたため、2つ削除したところ解決しました。

Comment: @TaigaMiura 良かったです もしよければ、回答に付いているチェックマークを押して、[回答を承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)して頂けると嬉しいです。あるいは[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)も歓迎します！